# Make a method wait for right click to go to next step (C# form)

Tags: c#, mouseevent, right-click

well, I'm writing a bot that will use certain coordinates on screen and then will simulate 15 clicks on them (every click with different coordinates). I already made it work with coordinates I entered manually on the code but now I need a way to record those coordinates. What i wanted to do is: the users press a button, then the program shows a messagebox saying "right click the main menu", the user right clicks that and those coordinates will be recorded on an array, then the program will show a second messagebox asking to right click the next button and so... My problem is that I don't know how to make the method wait for the user to right click to continue.

I tested my program by making an event that would trigger everytime I right click and show the coordinates in a messagebox, using a UserActivityHook class with contains the event OnMouseActivity:

```
 UserActivityHook actHook;
    void MainFormLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        actHook = new UserActivityHook(); 
        // crate an instance with global hooks
        // hang on events
        actHook.OnMouseActivity+=new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoved);         
    }

    public void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Clicks > 0)
        {
            if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Right))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("X:" + e.X + " Y:" + e.Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've trying to do something like:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        RecordMacro(cords, 1);          
    }

    public void RecordMacro(int coordinates[][], int slotnumber){

      MessageBox.show("Right click main menu");
      //saves coordinates on [0][0] and [0][1] 
      WaitForRightClickAndSaveCords(coordinates[][]);

      MessageBox.show("Right click resupply button");
      //saves coordinates on [1][0] and [1][1]
      WaitForRightClickAndSaveCords(coordinates[][]);
      ...
    }
```

I'm still a newbie and this is my first question in StackOverflow (I usually find an answer browsing here and don't have the need to ask myself) so I'll gladly accept any critics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easiest to implement using C# 5.0's asynchrony model.  We'll start out by creating a method that will generate a `Task` that will be completed when your conditions are met.  It will do this by creating a `TaskCompletionSource`, adding a handler to the event, and marking the task as completed in the handler.  Throw in some boilerplate code to make sure the handler is removed when done, return the `Task` from the completion source, and we're set:

```
public static Task<Point> WhenRightClicked(this UserActivityHook hook)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Point>();
    MouseEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Clicks > 0 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            hook.OnMouseActivity -= handler;
        }
    };
    hook.OnMouseActivity += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now you can write:

```
public async void RecordMacro(int[][] coordinates, int slotnumber)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Right click main menu");
    Point mainMenuPosition = await actHook.WhenRightClicked();
    MessageBox.Show("Right click resupply button");
    Point resupplyButtonPosition = await actHook.WhenRightClicked();
}
```

Comment: `+1` I like this method, though the (potential) length of RecordMacro suggests to me some kind of queue, so that the actions aren't hard-coded.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was merely demonstrating how to call the method; the whole point is that once you have the method using it becomes *very* easy.  If he wants to call it in a loop, he can do so.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. thanks for the clear answer, and yeah, as Bradley says, I was just showing the intention there with the "unorthodox manual way of saving the coordinates", I was thinking on using a loop.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, for some reason "WhenRightClicked" was being treated as an extension method so I had to remove "this" from the parameters in order to make it work:
WhenRightclicked(UserActivityHook hook) instead of WhenRightclicked(this UserActivityHook hook)

Comment: @IvarDonado I intended it to be an extension method.  If you don't want it to be an extension method, you're more than welcome to change that, but it was a very deliberate decision on my part.

Comment: Oh, sorry. As I said before I'm still a newbie in programing, I didn't even know about extension methods until now that I looked it up to check why I was getting the error message "Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class". I just wanted to add the comment in case someone that find this thread looking for this answer gets the same error while using this method on a non-static class. In anycase, you were a HUGE help, I had been trying to do this since yesterday without success.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad number of ways to make this work, none of which you should remotely do. The reason is, that assuming you managed to stop execution of the thread with `WaitForRightClick`, you would be blocking the UI thread!

By doing *that*, you prevent the user from being able to click on the element you want (among lots of other reasons to *never* block the UI thread).

You could thread it or use asynchornous methods, as Servy suggests. This blocks the *method* (or executes it asynchronously) without blocking the UI thread itself.

While more complex, you could also queue up a bunch of object representing a "ClickTarget". Then, you would listen on the right-click event and record the associated coordinates with the current `ClickTarget`, dequeue to get the next instruction, and so on.

The complete code would be too long for StackOverflow, but to give you some ideas:

```
public class ClickTarget
{
    Point Coordinates {get; set;}
    String TargetName {get; set;}
}

Queue<ClickTarget> clickTargets;
//Obviously you instantiate/populate this somewhere

private void onRightClick(...)
{
   ClickTarget target = clickTargets.Dequeue();
   target.Coordinates = clickLocation;

   MessageBox.Show("Please click on " + clickTargets.Peek().TargetName);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of using queues. I hadn't used them since a time some years ago when I was trying to show in a graphic enviroment some multilinked node lists. thanks you for your advice.